# A confusion about using pinia in the Vue project

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

In my Vue project, I use the permission.js file for permission control

In the main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './stores'
import './permission'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

In the stores/index.js

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
const store = createPinia()
export default store
```

And in the permission.js

```
import router from './router'
import userStore from '@/stores/modules/user'
const userStore = userPinia()
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (!userStore.getUserCode) {
        await userStore.actUserInfo()
    }
    next()
})
```

Then the project reported an error‘getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?’

I commented out the code line 'const userStore=userPinia()' in the permission. js file and replaced it with userPinia(), then the project is OK

The following is the modified permission.js file

```
import router from './router'
import userStore from '@/stores/modules/user'
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (!userStore().getUserCode) {
        await userStore().actUserInfo()
    }
    next()
})
```

So，can anyone answer my confusion and why this situation is happening?